# IEnumerable / Enumerable with Double/Int; Beginner

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, enumerable

I'm new to C# coming from python, and am unclear on exactly how the `IEnumerable` object behaves, even after having read the MSDN documentation.

For instance, the `IEnumerable` requires an int, but the following code works fine:

```
IEnumerable<double> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2));
```

However,

```
IEnumerable<double> square_ = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
```

Throw's the compilation error that you cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable double'

I'm not really sure if this is just a fundamental misunderstanding of how Enumerable works, how objects work in C#, or something else entirely, and would greatly appreciate help and some guidance on where to read for a novice to get a better idea.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I don't think it throws an exception, what you mean is a compilation error.

Comment: Correct, sorry Neme; again an misnomer having come from an interpreted language :).

Comment: This question is far too broad, as it involves a number of misconceptions on your part, as well as imprecise use of domain-specific terminology. For example, the error message you describe is not _"thrown"_ (something that happens only at run-time, with exceptions), but rather is simply a compile-time error. Also, the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface (not _"object"_) does not _"require an int"_, in any scenario. ...

Comment: ... And the code that _"works fine"_ does so because there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `double`. The error you get is related to a completely different issue, having to do with variance in generic types. Explaining all of this in detail to a sufficient degree is far beyond the scope of a good Stack Overflow question, especially given all of the unrelated parts of your question.

Comment: apologies if my question was too rambling in scope. i hope you can forgive my syntax errors also, as i've just picked up the language and the differences between things like interfaces and objects are still beyond my total comprehension. feel free to close it or suggest  rephrasing if you think you can better direct me to a resource that makes sense for my knowledge level so that somebody else might find help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`Math.Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `double`, so the `.Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2));` returns a `IEnumerable<double>`, so exactly the type you declared.

The [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `IEnumerable<int>` that isn't compatible with a `IEnumerable<double>`.

Clearly you could:

```
IEnumerable<double> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => (double)x);
```

This would cast the single elements of the `Enumerable.Range` to `double`, by using a lambda function `int -> double` (that from an `int x` returns a `double`)

Comment: thanks, this does a great job of explaining the type conversion going on. I should probably reread the docs. it's just exhausting reading and remembering the docs of every System generic method you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the defintion of [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that it returns a double.

Therefore,

```
.Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2))
```

is [projecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693038.aspx) out a new `IEnumerable<double>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a matter of return type:

`Enumerable.Range(1, 100);` returns `IEnumerable<int>` check MSDN:
[Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Math.Pow` returns `double`, Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are trying to set a `IEnumerable<double>` type, hence the `Enumerable.Range(1, 100)` will not work.

Using Linq you project the `ints` to `doubles` with the `Select(x => Math.Pow(x, 2))` which gives you back `IEnumerable<double>`

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable.Range(1, 100);

returns an IEnumerable value

while

```
Math.Pow(x, 2)
```

returns Double.

Therefore, when you try the first option, you get a conversion error (your var expects  IEnumerable, or simply Double type, but gets  IEnumerable instead).

you can try something like

```
IEnumerable<double> squares = (IEnumerable<double>)Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
```